# mono balanced to stereo minijack lead

Tags: audio-recording

i was making a lead to attach a balanced shotgun mike to a 
Panasonic NV-GS230 DV camera, minijack stereo mike input.
 This is now interesting because i made the lead,
 Ring to negative polarity for balanced mono
 Tip to positive polarity for balanced mono
 Sleeve ground.
 it worked Really very well, but i suspect one of the stereo tracks
  on my DV tape is out of phase?
  what do you guys reckon?

Comment: What makes you think it's out of phase?

Answer (score 1):

If the input is expecting a stereo signal & you're instead sending it both sides of a balanced output, then yes, you will be 180° out of phase, as that's the whole idea of the balanced signal - each pole is out of phase with the other.

When the signal arrives at the other end, one pole is inverted & the two signals them summed - this makes any noise picked up on the way out of phase & therefore cancels itself out.

You actually need to unbalance the signal yourself, then send the same signal to both sides of the stereo input.

Send the cold pin [usually pin 3] and the shield [pin 1] to the sleeve, then the hot pin [pin 2] to the ring. Bridge the ring to the tip [connect the 2 together in other words]

You really don't want long cables if you're doing this, as they are liable to interference.

This is the best pic I could find of how to do it, courtesy of [Photobucket](http://s1103.photobucket.com/user/andrewrode123/media/XLR_to_TRS_Wiring.jpg.html)

[image]